# Несколько обработчиков для нескольких input submit в одной jsp-страничке

Tags: spring-mvc, java, java-ee, jsp, spring

Не могу четко сформулировать запрос для поисковика, поэтому пишу сюда.
На страничке есть куча input submit, которые должны иметь различные обработчики - один сервлет с множеством методов (SpringMVC). Так как я пишу веб-приложения на скорую руку, без основополагающих знаний в теории, то не знаю, следует мне каждый submit помещать в отдельную form или есть какой-то другой путь? Т.е.:

```
...
<form method="POST" action="/add_handler">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
<form method="POST" action="/modify_handler">
    <input type="submit" value="Modify" />
</form>
<form method="POST" action="/delete_handler">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Как правильно?

Comment: @nightin_gale, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Можете одну фору сабмитить, но не простыми кнопками sbmit, конечно, а из скрипта. 
Я частенько так делаю (правда, здесь методы распиливаются не по пути, а по параметру):

```
<form method="POST" action="/action">
    <input type="hidden" name="signal" value="" />

    <input type="button" value="Add" oncklik="add()" />
    <input type="button" value="Modify" oncklik="modify()" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete" oncklik="delete()" />

</form>

<script>
    function add() {
        jQuery("form input[name=signal]").val("add");
        jQuery("form").submit();
    }

    function modify() {
        jQuery("form input[name=signal]").val("modify");
        jQuery("form").submit();
    }

   function delete() {
        jQuery("form input[name=signal]").val("delete");
        jQuery("form").submit();
    }
</scipt>
```

Но если вам это очень нужно, можете в скрипте и *action* у формы подменять (вместо установки параметра).

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать params для того, чтобы на сервере разделить обработчики для различных форм: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers

Comment: Если несложно, можете привести пример вместе с JSP кодом. )

Comment: @nightin_gale, JSP код, что это вообще за зверь такой...

JSP тут ни при чём, вам сказали распилите обработчики по параметру. А ссылка указывает на то, как это сделать на сервере в Spring MVC.

К примеру, с параметром **signal**:

    @RequestMapping(value = "/action", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="signal=add")
    public void add(){}